# Magento Subscription with automatic payment

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-community, payment-methods

We are planning to sell a webservice with a subscription period of one month. This means the customer subscribes our service for an unlimited time and gets an invoice every month after we (or our payment provider) automatically charged his credit card.

Is this possible with Magento? Which extensions might be suitable for us? Do we need to get a custom solution? Are recurring profiles a possible solution? Which payment providers offer this?

I made some research and I am not sure which solution suits our needs. We already had bad experiences with an extension (http://www.itabs.de/store/magescription) where it turned out, that the customer would have to pay every month manually. I found the [Subscriptions and Recurring Payments by aheadWorks](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments-by-aheadworks.html) but I am not sure if this is the best solution. Can you recommend a direction where to go?

P.S.: We are in Europe (EU) if it matters.